# Disconnect with linkedin authentication in Django displays blank screen

Tags: django, linkedin-api, python-social-auth, django-socialauth

I want a user to be able to disconnect from linkedin in my application, but it displays a blank screen.

```
<div class="my-2 my-lg-0 mx-5">
            <strong class='text-light mr-2'> Hi {{ user.username }} </strong>
              <a href="{% url 'social:disconnect' 'linkedin-oauth2' %}" class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Logout</a>

</div>
```

This is the url for the django_social_auth

```
path(r'', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
```

I want the user to be disconnected from his linkedin account if he clicks the logout button.

Comment: `disconnect` is not the same as `logout`. Disconnect will remove the relationship between your user and the LinkedIn account, the user won't be able to login using LinkedIn again.

Comment: Yes exactly what I want

Comment: OK, then a few more things to check, are you invoking the disconnect with a `POST` request? Is the user "valid" to disconnect? That means: does it have a valid password or any other social account that will let the user log back in? There are some details about disconnection here https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/logging_out.html

Comment: I am using a post request 
<form method="post" action="{% url 'social:disconnect' 'linkedin-oauth2' %}">
                  {% csrf_token %}

                      <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">
                          Logout
                      </button>
                  </form>
The documentation doesn't really state anything.

Comment: Is the user valid to disconnect? Does it have a valid password or another social account as the docs say?

Comment: I honestly do not know, and the docs doesn't give much clarity and how to implement those, I have implemented everything in the docs already